# Is it possible to make force equal a value rather then adding force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My current code is:

```
public class scri : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpforce = 3;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public int CanJump = 1;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        CanJump = 1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && CanJump > 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f) * jumpforce, ForceMode.Impulse);  
            CanJump = CanJump - 1;           
        }

    
    } 
}
```

Which allows a air jump as  if you use the air jump any significant amount of time after the first jump since it only adds force gravity is pulling it down too much for the second jump to make much difference.

I've tried looking through documentation but couldn't find anything that would be useful.

Comment: Btw the usage of `CanJump` is a bit odd .. sounds like that should rather be a `bool` with two states `true` or `false` ..

Comment: I have it like that, so the player can have a double jump and eventually triple jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force is force. It would need to counter the force of gravity to balance out the final velocity.

What you can do though as said is overwrite the final target velocity directly and simply do e.g.

```
var velocity = rb.velocity;
velocity.y = jumpVelocity;
rb.velocity = velocity;
```